# How to connect to local derby database with ij when db runs on a different port, getting ERROR 08001

Tags: jdbc, derby

My derby local database name is - `data` and it is running on a port - `11377`

So, I tried executing the command in my system by referring to Apache Derby Site document page - `connect 'jdbc:derby:data;create=true';`. But with this I couldn't connect to my db.

As it is on a different port, I'd even tried `connect 'jdbc:derby:data:11377;create=true';`. For that, I'm getting the following error,

```
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:data:11377;create=true'; 
ERROR 08001: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:data:11377;create=true
```

I couldn't connect to the database as it is running on a some other port - `11377`

Can someone guide me, how I can connect to the database.

Comment: `jdbc` that's the keyword. This one had worked for me -  `connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:11377/data';` under `IJ` the ***Apche Derby CLI based DB Client*** Thanks! and Thanks for tagging it under `jdbc`.

Comment: Just to note down, -  `connect 'jdbc:derby:data:11377;create=false'` also doesn't work

Comment: Yes, in place db, it is `localhost` and `port` as `database` runs on a different `port` *derby://localhost:11377/data*